# Cumulative values in for loop?

Tags: python, for-loop

Is there a way to get the "cumulative" values in a Python for-loop? In Java there is the way of += to a variable during each loop iteration and it would continue to add it on. Is there an option like this available in Python?

Comment: Python has `+=`. What's the problem?

Comment: python has '+=' operator.

Comment: I understand why people would think this is a stupid question in general, but perhaps this is confusing for people moving over from Java and or beginning to learn/understand Python so it would perhaps be nice to not downvote someone for not knowing all the functionality of a language, in the end, everyone misses a thing or two in all languages, that's why we are here.. to ask questions concerning programming and the question itself is not ill-written or poorly presented is it?

Comment: @Torxed not my downvote, but the question really doesn't show any research effort. Either OP didn't open a term and try `+=` in 3 seconds, or he did, but it failed in some way, and he's really asking about that. (But if the latter is the case, the question should show what he tried and ask about that.)

Comment: Fair enough i guess, just me trying to see the good in all the bad :)

Answer (score 4):

So *many* ways. Python calls these [the "in-place" operators](http://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.iadd).

You've also got functional approaches like [`sum`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum) and more general accumulators like [`reduce`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce), which in Python 3 moved to [functools](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.reduce).

```
acc = 0
for i in range(10):
  acc += i
```

or

```
acc = sum(range(10))
```

or

```
from operator import add
from functools import reduce
acc = reduce(add, range(10))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foo = 0
for i in range(0, 12):
    foo += 1
print(foo)
```

Comment: Thanks I forgot about initializing it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a `+=` operator in Python.

```
x = 0

for i in range(10):
    x += 1

print x
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(0, 5):
    print i
```

Output:

```
0
1
2
3
4
```

Or, if you want to go by more than one:

```
for i in range(0, 10, 2):
    print i
```

Output:

```
0
2
4
6
8
```

Comment: I don't think this addresses the question. The question seems to be about accumulating values, not looping over a range.

Comment: @kojiro Isn't that essentially the same thing?

Comment: No. Accumulation requires a loop at some level, but a loop does not imply accumulation.

Comment: @kojiro Well, the value of `i` is accumulating over each iteration, so it's basically the same thing...

Comment: It's not accumulating over each iteration, it's iterating over each iteration. Accumulation is an operation that reduces the iterable to a single value. This is just iterating over the iterable.